# Show that $(\sin, \cos, \sin \cos, \sin^2, \cos^2)$ is a Basis of $V = \operatorname{Span}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, linear-independence

Hey I have problems with this exercise
Let $B = (\sin, \cos, \sin \cos, \sin^2, \cos^2)$, and let $V = \operatorname{Span}(B)$ be a subset of $Abb(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$. Show that $B$ is a basis of $V$.

So what I need to prove is that the vectors of $B$ are linear independent.

$a\sin+ b\cos+ c\sin \cos+ d\sin^2+ e\cos^2=0 \Leftrightarrow a=b=c=d=e=0$

I tried to prove different cases.

[I EDITED MY ANSWER]

We have here that $b+e=0$,and so we have $b=-e$.

If we take $\pi=x$ we have $-b+e=0$ wwhich means $b=e \Rightarrow b=e=0$

If we take $\pi/2=x$ we have $a+ d=0$ so $a=-d$

If we take $3\pi/2=x$ we have $-a+d=0$ so $a=d \Rightarrow a=d=0$

From this follows that $c=0$ and our assumption.
Everything right now?

Comment: for the linear combination of functions to be zero, it has to vanish at every point, not just one point.

Comment: Ah okay, then I will continue my solution

Comment: Is now everything right @hunter ?

Comment: yes, it could be written a little more neatly but you have the idea (plug in a lot of points and deduce the coefficients are zero piece by piece)